# Aggregate based on values (not groups) in r

Tags: count, aggregate

I have a data frame that looks like this:

TABLE 1:

| Sp.1 | Sp.2 | Sp.3 | Sp.4 | Sp.5 | Sp.6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | c | c | e |
| c | b | c | d | c | d |
| c | b | a | e | c | c |
| c | b | a | a | d | c |
| d | b | a | b | d | d |
| e | a | a | b | d | b |

I need to aggregate the data based on values (a-e) for the output to produce a table counting the number of occurrences, which looks like this:

TABLE 2:

|  | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sp.1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| Sp.2 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sp.3 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Sp.4 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Sp.5 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| Sp.6 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

I was hoping this community will help me come up with a code for this.

As mentioned earlier, I was expecting to find an argument within the "aggregate" function or may use a different function to obtain a table containing the total number of occurrences of either of a-e for each species as shown in Table 2.

Thank you so much!